# Find identical IP from database and combine it to one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "ips" that contains all of my users IPs.
I want to find duplicated accounts and report it for me.
I want to see all users that have the same IP, for example:
"a" has the same ip as "b", and "c" has the same ip as "d".
So I want to get a query that gets me-

```
User 1: "a", User 2: "b", ip: 127.0.0.1
User 1: "c", User 2: "d", ip: 256.0.0.2
```

What's the best query to do so? (PHP/Mysql)

Comment: What is the logic here? A user can't login from 2 different IPs or two users can't login from the same IP? Both seem flawed. Also `256.0.0.2` shouldn't be an IP. You should store your IPs as long ints so you can use numerical functions on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select ip, group_concat(user_name) as users
from ips
group by ip
having count(*) > 1
```